# Get NuGet installed dll's to travel to another TFS workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I am working on projects in a TFS environment. The work is distributed to several machines with different developers. A person, who is installing a dependency with NuGet into a project, get's actual dll's to his machine. When another user on another machine Gets Latest Version, he has the project with the dependency, but not the actual dll's, so the dep. is marked with an exclamation mark.

We manually add dll's to a source control, and have to be calling Get Latest Version of a Source Control Window, not on in the solution explorer on a different machine, in order to get the dependency dll.

Is there a way to just make TFS store dll's automatically, to facilitate the process discribed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the dependencies at compile time. Take a look at this [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)